# Scraping the href value of anchor in Ruby

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, screen-scraping, scrape

Working on this project where I have to scrape a "website," which is just a an html file in one of the local folders. Anyway, I've been trying to scrape down to the href value (a url) of the anchor tag for each *student* object. I am also scraping for other things, so ignore the rest. Here is what I have so far:

```
def self.scrape_index_page(index_url) #responsible for scraping the index page that lists all of the students
    #return an array of hashes in which each hash represents one student.
    html = index_url
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(html))
    # doc.css(".student-name").first.text
    # doc.css(".student-location").first.text
    #student_card = doc.css(".student-card").first
    #student_card.css("a").text
end
```

[image]

Here is one of the student profiles. They are all the same, so I'm just interested in scraping the href url value.

```
<div class="student-card" id="eric-chu-card">
   <a href="students/eric-chu.html">
      <div class="view-profile-div">
         <h3 class="view-profile-text">View Profile</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="card-text-container">
         <h4 class="student-name">Eric Chu</h4>
         <p class="student-location">Glenelg, MD</p>
      </div>
   </a>
</div>
```

thanks for your help!

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Please share `url` or html document sample

Comment: I am trying to get the href value of the student-card class containers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you get an anchor tag in Nokogiri, you can get the href like this:

```
anchor["href"]
```

So in your example, you could get the href by doing the following:

```
student_card = doc.css(".student-card").first
href = student_card.css("a").first["href"]
```

If you wanted to collect all of the href values at once, you could do something like this:

```
hrefs = doc.css(".student-card a").map { |anchor| anchor["href"] }
```

Comment: Only thing, I'm getting an error for the href: no implicit conversion of String into Integer. Wonder what gives?

Comment: Sorry about that. When you use the `css` method, it returns a `Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet`. You want to get the href from the `Nokogiri::XML::Element` inside the NodeSet. In your example, `student_card.css("a").first["href"]` should return the href.